# Error in Java Method Cant get it to print to the console

Tags: java, methods

I'm not sure where I went wrong but I could use some help. I'm new to JAVA and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Just trying to get the items in the public void method to print to my console.

```
public class HomersDonutShop {
public static void main (String[] args) {
//Creates flavor array
String[] donutFlavors = new String[4];

donutFlavors[0]= "Chocolate";
donutFlavors[1]= "Vanilla";
donutFlavors[2]= "Chocolate With Sprinkles";
donutFlavors[3]= "Blueberry";

//default is chocolate. prints string with array selected
System.out.println("You picked " +donutFlavors[0]+"."+" Great choice!!");
//creates donut rating
final int donutRating[] = new int[5];

donutRating[0] = 1;
donutRating[1] = 2;
donutRating[2] = 3;
donutRating[3] = 4;
donutRating[4] = 5;

//default is 5 prints string with array selected
System.out.println("You gave " +donutFlavors[0]+" donuts"+" a rating of"+ " "+donutRating[4]);

        }

public  void makeDonuts(){
donutCount = donuCount + 1;
System.out.println("Time to mke more donuts."+" MMMMMMMM DOOOONNNUUUUTSSS.");

            }
public void buyMoreIngredients() {
int ingredients = 10;
while (ingredients >= 10)
System.out.println(ingredients);
ingredients--;
    if (ingredients <=1) {
        System.out.println("Time to go shopping");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Two things:  you don't actually call any methods in your `main` method (like `makeDonuts` or `buyMoreIngredients`, and `buyMoreIngredients` suffers from an infinite loop since it doesn't have braces around the part you *really* want to iterate over.

Comment: What error? Are you referring to the **compile** error that is caused by `donutCount = donuCount + 1;`, since neither `donutCount` nor `donuCount` are declared anywhere? If you remove that line, the code runs and prints two lines of text.